# MS Access Sum and IIF expression

Tags: ms-access, conditional-statements

I'm with a non-profit. We divide the state up into 16 regions for administrative purposes. I'm trying to find out how many members live in each region. We have 4 different types of members too. There's a table that lists all the members. There is also a table in which we have listed all the towns in the state and put in which of our regions the town is in. For the first member type the record has the value "1" in the TYPE field. I'm trying to write an expression that basically says this. If the TYPE field has a "1" in it, then the condition is true, return 1. Else return 0. Then sum up all the ones.

I didn't build the database or the query. This is the expression that was already there: INDIVIDUAL: Sum(IIf([Membership.TYPE]=1,1,0)) The sum that it comes up with just doesn't make sense.

Edit: I hope I did this right.  Here is a table showing what information the query returns except for the 502 and the 96 which I put there as a check.  The values in that one column add up to 502 but they should add up to 674.  The 96 should be 113.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxe6v.png)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that expression. Why doesn't result make sense? Edit question to show sample data as a text table and expected result as well as the SQL statement.

Comment: Sample data should be provided as a text table in question so it can be copy/pasted, not an image. Or provide SQL to build and populated tables. Need the raw data. Need the attempted SQL. Must be something wrong with your data because there is nothing wrong with what you have provided so far.

Comment: Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: tip: you can use the query editor or the relationships tool to show Access table relationships.  use  printscreen and a tool like paint.3d to grab the picture.  Access tables are easier as you can just export the data as text and then cut and paste them into your question.  Open the table you want to add to your question.  Then go to External Data on the ribbon and choose export as text.  It shouldn't take long to find acceptable export settings.  I like to paste the tables into code blocks where it looks neater.

Comment: Nothing wrong with, say, FAMILY _sum_. If this should be 113, some of the FAMILY _values_ are incorrect.